# Can't avoid div stretching over another one

Tags: html, layout, overflow

Switching from tables to divs for layout purposes sounds an attractive decision, yet it's very painful. I haven't still been able to use `float` and `oveflow` properly to get divs aligned properly. Here are I have the following html and css:

#### HTML

```
<div class="div-row">
  <div id="divOfficers" class="div-column">DIVOFFICERS</div>
  <div id="divTasks">DIVTASKS</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.div-row {
    width:100%;
    overflow:clear;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.div-column {
    margin-right:3px;
    float:left;
}
#divOfficers {
    border:3px solid red;
    height:80px;
    width:200px;
    color:red;
}
#divTasks{
    width:300px;
    height:80px;
    border:10px solid orange;
    color:orange;
}
```

Basically, I need the `divTasks` to stand right to the `divOfficers`, but without stretching over it. But here's what I get:

[image]

I've cleared the overflow in the parent div but as you can see that does not help. What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just give a float:right to divtasks as well as you did float:left with divofficers. if it is what you want than your problem solved or let me know if you need something else to do and put your code on jsfiddle please as it will help a lot

Comment: Yeah, I had just achieved it with float:left. :) Thank you.. I think giving it float:left would be a better option if someone wanted to have another div to the right of the `divTasks`.

Comment: yes you are right but in case of two divs float means that if first div is having float left and second one can have float right  or left both will be fine. but the thing is sticky property that left means it will start from left

Answer (score 1):

Try use CSS3 code, If you use float maybe have problem with long content

```
.div-row {
    width:100%;
    overflow:clear;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display: table;
}
.div-column {
    margin-right:3px;    
}
#divOfficers {
    border:3px solid red;
    height:80px;
    width:200px;
    color:red;
    display: table-cell;
}
#divTasks{
    width:300px;
    height:80px;
    border:10px solid orange;
    color:orange;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vsok/dqmdv7oa/

Comment: `display: table` has always got my attention as it seems to be an easy way around this problem. But that makes me think if it has any side effect.

Comment: I think use display: table is working fine if your site support modern browser

Comment: Or can use  display:inline-block; instead of float